# How to skip open folders (and skip open files) when moving items using VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I made a VBscript to move Windows folders, and the script gets stuck when it reaches a folder that a user has open.  Is there a way I can change my script so that it skips open folders and skips open files?

---

```
Dim fso, directory, item, group, dateStamp, NumberFilesDeleted, text, MoveFoldersErrorInfo, MoveFilesErrorInfo, objLogFile

On error resume Next 

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Move folders in the temp folder to To_Be_Deleted folder and check for errors
fso.MoveFolder "E:\Projects\temp\*" , "E:\Projects\To_Be_Deleted"
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
   MoveFoldersErrorInfo =  "Error: " & Err.Number & " Error (Hex): " & Hex(Err.Number) & Err.Source & " Description: "  & Err.Description
   Err.Clear
End If

'Move files in the temp folder to To_Be_Deleted folder and check for errors
fso.MoveFile "E:\Projects\temp\*" , "E:\Projects\To_Be_Deleted"
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MoveFilesErrorInfo =  "Error: " & Err.Number & " Error (Hex): " & Hex(Err.Number)  & Err.Source & " Description: "  & Err.Description
    Err.Clear
End If
```

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent `robocopy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vbscript is extremely slow with fileoperations and if there was a reliable way to check if a file is open it would even further slow down the process. You could just neglect the open files, with "on error resume next" as you do in your scriptsample.

I know of only one reason why you would wanna check and that is forcing the closing of the file with a utility like psfile.exe from systernals but i suppose your users wouldn't be happy with that.

As an external program psfile can be run from your script and check and if desired close open files, so you could run it first on the handled folder with the /c parameter (force close) and then do the move from batch of script.

Answer (score 0):

VBScript is not very reliable in move/delete operations with files. Use DOS commands instead, it will delete/move files even **open by users**.

You will have to create folders yourself, that is a minus. But it is guaranteed to work and will not give you error messages.

Your code could look similar to this:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
wshShell.Run "cmd /c mkdir " & strNewDestination & "\" & strFolder, 0, True 
wshShell.Run "cmd /c copy /y " & strFolder & "\*.* " & strNewDestination & "\" & strFolder, 0, True
wshShell.Run "cmd /c del /y " & strFolder & "\*.*", 0, True
```